# Laravel table relationship for getting user list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm working on a laravel 5 application.
I have 3 tables:

```
table A: 'users' 

id   |    name
————————————————
1    |    Dave
2    |    Robet
3    |    Jimmy
4    |    Daniel
```

and Table B classroom_users

```
user_id | classroom_id 
1       | 5            
4       | 5            
3       | 6  
4       | 5
```

I need to return all users 'name' for classroom 5

Please let me know what is the best way to do that. Trough model or Database join

**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: do you have models and relationship defined ?

Comment: @jaysingkar Yes I have the models but don't know what methods to use for relationship.

Comment: ok.. you can use `belongsToMany()` will show you how

Comment: what is the name of classrooms and users table?

Comment: It's same as the table name.

Comment: Check the answer.. let me know if you get any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have models and its relationships will be defined as below:

**Classroom Model:**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'classroom_users','classroom_id','user_id');
}
```

**User Model:**

```
public function classrooms(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserClassrooms::class,'classroom_users','user_id','classroom_id');
}
```

Now, in controller you can retrieve the users belonging to the classroom id 5 as below:

```
$classroom_id = 5 ;//change this to the id you want
$users = Classroom::find($classroom_id)->users()->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I got:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user_user_classrooms" does not exist
LINE 1: ...er_id" as "pivot_user_id" from "users" inner join "user_user...

Comment: update the users method to include table name, check the update

Comment: Another error :(  
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column user_classrooms.user_classrooms_id does not exist

Comment: I just copied your codes over there.
`public function UsersList(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_classrooms');
    }`

and 

`public function usersclassrooms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserClassrooms::class, 'user_classrooms');
    }`

Comment: what is the name of class of user and classroom table's models

Comment: For users model it's just 'User' and for classrooms model it's 'UserClassrooms'

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. No there is no error now but it's returned only '[]'

Comment: How you are retrieving the data ?

Comment: This is what I got on var_dump():   
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#327 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: no no..  are you using this ? "$users = Classroom::find($classroom_id)->users()->get();"

Comment: Yes exactly:  
$List = UserClassroom::find(4)->users()->get();

die(var_dump($List));

Comment: replace `users()` with `UsersList()`

Comment: Oh I changed the UsersList to users but it's still same return :(

Comment: are you sure that you have the data in table.. I don't see any classroom 4 having users in posted table

Comment: OMG, yes you right man. I really really appreciate your help. Finally got the results. Thanks again.

Comment: It has an issue that doesn't return the all the data with calassroom_id 4 but it's return data with user_id. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: do you want both classroom and user data ?

Comment: I wish there is a way to specify column name for getting the data

Comment: you can use `select()` for that.

Comment: No I only need the users list who has classroom_id 4

Comment: Where I should add that select() ?

Comment: before `get()` `$users = Classroom::find($classroom_id)->users()->selectRaw('users.name')->get();` This will only get the user's name.

Comment: That part is ok but the issue is it's returning data for the user_id 4 not classroom_id 4. On the table classroom_users it should get all classroom_id 4 and return users with specified user_id on classroom_users table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123794/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-david-titan).

Comment: @David sorry gt offline.. comment here when you are avaiable

Comment: Thanks again man, I really appreciate your help.
So take a look at the table. classrooms. I have 3 classrooms with classroom_id 5 and each one of them has a user assigned with and I need to return those users
On this code that we have now it'e selecting the users with user_id 5 instead of classroom_id 5

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has introduced Pivot tables, which works like this

```
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

You can read more pivot on [Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)